# Elasticsearch Version 8 minimum_should_match

Tags: elasticsearch

How to write minimum_should_match in Elasticsearch Version 8 like this

```
"minimum_should_match": {
      "low_freq" : 60%,
      "high_freq" : 40%
}
```

Comment: Did you already red the doc ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html

Comment: @Paulo yes i read it , do you know how to write it ?

Comment: Could you explain what behaviour you are looking for ?

Comment: @Paulo

the behaviour i need is with Percentage like the old version 7 

how to do this in version 8 without fixed integer

Comment: I think he might be talking about https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-common-terms-query.html. I'm just reading through now, but it appears to be saying you don't need to do that: "This option can be omitted as the Match can skip blocks of documents efficiently, without any configuration, provided that the total number of hits is not tracked.".  If you think you do, please provide a COMPLETE query, and description of what you want it to do.